# Issues when trying to delete entries from Database with button dropdown - Entity

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a button dropdown in which each line item consists of a person's name that is read in from a database table

```
            <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" id="overrideLock" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Override <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach (var person in Model.Where(person => person.userName != null))
        {
            <li class="overrideListItem">

                <input type="hidden" name="username" value="@person.userName"/>

                <a>@person.userName</a>
            </li>
        }
          </ul>
          </div>
```

I would like to be able to click a line item (persons name) in the button dropdown and have it replace their name in the database with the name of the current logged in user. I have started the entity controller code, but am not all the way there.

Controller Code:

```
        public void OverrideLock(string username)
    {
        var context = new PortalEntity();
        var personToReplace = context.LockedPerson.Where(p => p.userName == username);
    }
```

I am using the hidden value to pass the username value, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To get the current user you can use the User object in your controller.  One way to obtain is HttpContext.Current.User.  Then you will have the current users username from that object.

You might need to add a using statement for System.Web.Httpcontext.